# Sencha Touch mobile website startup time

Tags: extjs, sencha-touch-2.1

This is probably a newbie question but....

I am developing my first mobile website using Sencha Touch 2. I now deployed the app to my Hosting server but.....it takes about 11 seconds before it even starts up ??

This is when I am running it in Chrome on my development machine. 
It does 247 request with a total of 1.8 MB.

```
247 requests  ❘  1.8 MB transferred  ❘  10.65 s (onload: 10.66 s, DOMContentLoaded: 352 ms)
```

Is this normal ?  I mean, this is only the framework stuff.

Thanks

Comment: In addition to Neil's answer, you can use YSlow which is plugin for Firefox and Chrome that tells you what you need to improve to make the loading of your app faster. The main thing you can do is reduce HTTP request by using sprites instead of multiple images, use only one CSS file, use on JS file...

Answer (score 2):

You need to concatenated and minimize all of the files that you use into one big file

Use [Sencha Command for Sencha Touch 2.1](http://docs.sencha.com/touch/2-1/#!/guide/command)

```
sencha app build
```

Comment: Question is tagged with Sencha 2.1 though and there has been some changes on Sencha Command between 2.0 and 2.1

Answer (score 1):

If you've deployed development version directly on server then overall loading time will increase. To deploy app, you should build your app with compressed css and js. Follow [this guide](http://docs.sencha.com/touch/2-1/#!/guide/building) to start with. After successful build you'll get minified version of js files. Consider compressing css files too. To compress CSS files, you can use [compass](http://compass-style.org/). Although, you've developed app already, consider going to [theming guide](http://docs.sencha.com/touch/2-1/#!/video/theming) that covers how to compress css files for production version.

As you've mentioned app is making 247 request. I assume that includes images too. You can base64 encode images directly into CSS files to avoid frequent communication with server. Another way to reduce image requests is to use **css sprites**.

SO also uses css sprites for different images seen here.